# Return the url of the generated image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I am trying to draw something on a image    , I  have done it by the code below

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg');

$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 6, 6, $ellipseColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

This code successfully draw the image , and I can see this on browser  . The generated html  for this code like

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" src="http://localhost/test/" width="786" height="413">
```

But I want to display that image in my own styled way   , like

```
<img src="" class="city_map" usemap="#city_map">
```

Is there any way I just can return an url for the generated image , and destroy it after using .

Comment: What about `<img src="http://localhost/test/" class="city_map" usemap="#city_map">`?

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/test/" class="city_map" usemap="#city_map">  this is automatically generated by php , hence I can't modify it .

Comment: Well then show us the PHP code where this HTML tag is generated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return the URL of the generated image any differently than your first example. Just remove the `style`-attribute and the the `class`-attribute you used in your second example:

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/" class="city_map" usemap="#city_map" />
```

Now the image will be formatted as described by the `city_map` CSS class definition (instead of the definition provided by the `style`-attribute)

To make the image similar as the first one you could use the following CSS:

```css
.city_map {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  width: 786px;
  height: 413px;
}
```

Comment: Actualy 

<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" src="http://localhost/test/" width="786" height="413">

this html is generated by the the php code below 

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg');

$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 6, 6, $ellipseColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);

I didn't write this . Hence I can't add what I want to img attribute

Comment: The PHP code in your question (and in your comment) produces the JPEG image not the HTML! Proof of this is the `header("Content-type: image/jpeg")` line, which tells the browser (via the HTTP header) that `image/jpeg` content is send (which is a JPEG image). Note that the other lines of code are also showing that an image is created and not the HTML...